Drupal 10 block visibility only if content has a specific term
It's been 7 years that I don't use Drupal
I want the visibility of a block only if there is a specific term in a specific taxonomy (vocabulary)

So I go in and I can only choose the whole vocabulary

I want to choose a term inside the "Category" in this case.
solution could be using PHP

something like...
<?PHP 
if content taxonomyid=8
return TRUE; ?>

but I forgot how to do it.

have you tried hook block view alter. refer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215820/alter-block-content for more information

If you decide to use a custom module then you can control the block visibility with the following code:
use \Drupal\block\Entity\Block;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;

/**
 * Implements hook_block_access().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_NAME_block_access(Block $block, $operation, AccountInterface $account) {

 $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load( YOUR_NODE_ID );

 if ($operation == 'view' && $block->getPluginId() == 'YOUR_BLOCK_ID') {
   if ($node->field_condition->value == FALSE) {
      return AccessResult::forbidden()->addCacheableDependency($block);
   }    
 }

 return AccessResult::neutral();
}


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
